# zend Unknown column 'telephone.number' in 'where clause' Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework

I got two nearly same function.

```
    public function getUserAndCommentAndTelephone($paged=NULL)
        {
     $select  = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)
             ->from('user',array('name','user_id'))
             ->join('comment', 'user.user_id = comment.user_id', array('comment_id','text','date'))
             ->join('telephone', 'telephone.telephone_id = comment.telephone_id', array('number'))
             ->order(array('comment.comment_id DESC'));
     if (null !== $paged) {
            $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select);
            $count = clone $select;
            $count->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
            $count->reset(Zend_Db_Select::FROM);
            $count->from('comment', new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*) AS `zend_paginator_row_count`'));
            $adapter->setRowCount($count);

            $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
            $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5)
                      ->setCurrentPageNumber((int) $paged);
            return $paginator;
    }
    return $this->fetchAll($select);
```

and another one with where clause in $select. This is only this one different between.

```
   public function getCommentAndUserByTelephone($number,$paged=null) {
    $select  = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)
             ->from('user',array('name','user_id'))
             ->join('comment', 'user.user_id = comment.user_id', array('text','comment_id','date'))
             ->join('telephone', 'telephone.telephone_id = comment.telephone_id', array('number'))
             ->order(array('comment.comment_id DESC'))
             ->where('telephone.number = ?', $number);
   if (null !== $paged) {
            $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select);
            $count = clone $select;
            $count->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
            $count->reset(Zend_Db_Select::FROM);
            $count->from('comment', new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*) AS `zend_paginator_row_count`'));
            $adapter->setRowCount($count);

            $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
            $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5)
                      ->setCurrentPageNumber((int) $paged);
            return $paginator;
    }

    return $this->fetchAll($select);         
        }
```

and on this with **where** clause a got error :
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'telephone.number' in 'where clause' 
when I COMMENT it  //->where('telephone.number = ?', $number); start working.
so this mine I something wrong with this WHERE clause.

Someone got idea how to change $select, with where clause to make it working.Thank

Comment: Do you have a column called 'number' in the 'telephone' table in your database?

Comment: yes. But it is not matter what I want to pick using **where** is not work.

Comment: This one is work on my data base: `SELECT name, comment_id, text, date, number
FROM user,
COMMENT , telephone
WHERE user.user_id = comment.user_id
AND telephone.telephone_id = comment.telephone_id
AND telephone.number =000
LIMIT 0 , 30`

Comment: The problem is in this lines             $count = clone $select;
            $count->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
            $count->reset(Zend_Db_Select::FROM):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're creating a new select object for the count, but when you reset the FROM clause this removes the joins as well. You'd need to repeat the joins in your count select for what you have to work. However, most of that code is unnecessary, as ZF can build the count query for you based on the select object you pass in.

Try this:

```
public function getCommentAndUserByTelephone($number,$paged=null) {
    $select  = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)
             ->from('user',array('name','user_id'))
             ->join('comment', 'user.user_id = comment.user_id', array('text','comment_id','date'))
             ->join('telephone', 'telephone.telephone_id = comment.telephone_id', array('number'))
             ->order(array('comment.comment_id DESC'))
             ->where('telephone.number = ?', $number);

   if (null !== $paged) {
        $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select);

        $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5)
                  ->setCurrentPageNumber((int) $paged);
        return $paginator;
    }

    return $this->fetchAll($select);         
}
```

That just reuses your existing select instead.